# is it possible to dynamically add images to bufferedImage

Tags: java, image, game-engine, bufferedimage

I'm working on a small game which uses images to generate rooms inside a level. I use the image so I can  read the different colors and setup a room accordingly using this code:

```
private void addImage(BufferedImage image, int x, int y){
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        boolean playerSpawned = false;
        Random r = new Random();
        int fails = 0;

        for (int imageX = x; imageX < w; imageX++)
            for (int imageY = y; imageY < h; imageY++){
                int pixel = image.getRGB(imageX, imageY);

                int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;

                if(blue == 255)
                    if((!playerSpawned && (r.nextInt(4) + 1) == 4) || fails == 3){
                    handler.addObject(new Player(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.player, handler,this));
                    playerSpawned = true;
                    } else {
                        fails++;
                    }
                if(blue == 200) // handle rotation
                    handler.addObject(new door(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.door,this,0));
                if(green == 0 && red == 0 && blue == 0)
                    if(r.nextInt(100) == r.nextInt(200))
                        handler.addObject(new enemy(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.enemy, handler,this));
            }

        for (int imageX = 0; imageX < w; imageX++)
            for (int imageY = 0; imageY < h; imageY++){
                int pixel = image.getRGB(imageX, imageY);

                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;

                if(red == 255)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.block,this,0));
                if(red == 200)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.block,this,1));
                if(red == 175)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.block,this,2));
                if(red == 150)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.block,this,3));
                if(red == 125)
                    handler.addObject(new Block(imageX * 32, imageY * 32, ID.block,this,4));
            }
    }
```

Here is an example of an image I use to generate the level. The black pixels are just empty areas while the red pixels generate blocks and the blue ones generate doors which opens on certain conditions.

[image]

The first room I generate using this method works fine. The problem is that I am not able to figure out how to add rooms to the level. I want to make it that I can add a room based on the direction the player leaves the room in.(If the player walks south trought a room I want it to generate a room south of him).

To detect the direction of the player I use this function which prints the right direction:

```
public room nextRoom(int xx, int yy){
        int numX = 0, numY = 0;

        if(xx > this.x + 1024 + 32){
            numX++;
            System.out.println("right");
        }
        if(xx < this.x){
            numX--;
        System.out.println("left");
        }
        if(yy > this.y + 576 + 32){
            System.out.println("up");
            numY++;
        }
        if(yy < this.y){
            System.out.println("down");
            numY--;
        }

        new room(content, numX, numY, manager, game, handler).toString();
        return new room(content, numX, numY, manager, game, handler);
    }
```

Here 'numX' and 'numY' are the coordinates of the room based the central room (the central room has coordinates (0,0) while the one right of it has coordinates (1,0). Then I use these coordinates to calculate the final size of the room in pixels)

This function returns the room which it should generate which then gets loaded like this:

```
addImage(new bufferedImageLoader().loadImage("/level_base.png"), room.getX(), room.getY());
            addImage(room.getContent(), room.getX(), room.getY());
```

'addImage()' is the function written above in the question!

The first item to be loaded here is a base and the second image is an overlay which determines the content of the room.

The problem is that whenever I try to load the new room only the background shows up and not the newly added blocks. Also it deletes the background of the room the player just left but leaves the blocks there...

Does anybody know how I could add rooms dynalically to this system?

Comment: Keep a `List<Shape>` that you draw with a for-loop. As one type of Shape you could have a rectangle with border and background and on it a door. I think this is easier, more dynamic and faster (pixel access is not that performant).

Comment: I'm using images to easelly create the rooms but if there is a better way to make them that would be better... I don't think that keeping each element in it's own array is the right solution because that would mean i need around 20 different lists for each element... However I have one arraylist for all the elements (all of them in the same one) which is filled and updated by the addImage() function.